# How to guarantee that when a process calls malloc(), it will allocate physical memory immediately?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management, malloc

I am looking for a way to pre-allocate memory to a process (PHYSICAL memory), so that it will be absolutely guaranteed to be available to the C++ heap when I call new/malloc. I need this memory to be available to my process regardless of what other processes are trying to do with the system memory. In other words, I want to reserve physical memory to the C++ heap, so that it will be available immediately when I call malloc().
Here are the details:

I am developing a real-time system. The system is composed of several memory-hungry processes. Process A is the mission-critical process and it must survive and be immune to bad behavior of any other processes. It usually fits in 0.5 GB of memory, but it sometimes needs as much as 2.5 GB. The other processes attempt to use any amount of memory.

My concern is that the other processes may allocate lots of memory, exhausting the physical memory reserves in the system.  Then, when Process A needs more memory FAST, it's not available, and the system will have to swap pages, which would take a long time.
It is critical that Process A get all the memory it needs without delay, whereas I'm fine with the other processes failing.

I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Edit:
Would SetProcessWorkingSetSize work? Meaning: Would calling this for a big enough amount of memory protect my process A from any other process in the system.

Comment: Real time in Windows? Good luck.

Comment: How do you expect to write RT software on a non-realtime OS?

Comment: Are you programming in user-mode?

Comment: 2.5GB of critical data... hmmm maybe its redesign time. :D

Comment: Using Windows - this is set in stone by now. RT wasn't the only constraint in this system. I just have to make the most of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you're looking for. It will force the OS to keep the pages in memory, as long as they're in the working set size (which is the function linked to by MK in his answer). However, there is no way to feed this memory to `malloc`/`new`- you'll have to implement your own memory allocator.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is weird because Windows 7 is not exactly the OS of choice for realtime applications.  That said, there appears to be an interface that might help you:

[AllocateUserPhysicalPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't entirely understand this, however I'm not sure the allocated physical pages would be employed by the CRT heap. I understand that to utilize them one must call VirtualAlloc to reserve memory, then MapUserPhysicalPages can map that to physical memory. However, I don't have access to those allocations made internally by the CRT, so I can't map them onto the physical pages I had allocated. Can I?